How can I use the value of ViewData in my script?
In my PageModel, I am setting the value of ViewData before returning to the view.
When I debug, I see that the ViewData has the expected value, \Testing\Development\Accounting\statements.png
// .cshtml.cs
public Task<IActionResult>OnGetViewFile(string fileName)
{
  var fileProvider = _fileServerProvider.GetProvider("/Accounting");
  var fileInfo = fileProvider.GetFileInfo(fileName);

  ViewData["FilePath"] = fileInfo.PhysicalPath;
  return Task.FromResult<IActionResult>(this.Page());
}

This is what the .cshtml looks like:
@page
@model AccountingProject.Pages.Statements.Statements_Model
@{
  var filePath = ViewData["FilePath"] as string; // when this is debugged it has the correct value
}

//html here

<script type="text/javascript">
  let viewFileName = '@filePath';  // why is it an empty string here?  How can I set viewFileName to the value of filePath?
  console.log(viewFileName);
</script>

I need to be able to use the value of filePath in the script, but have been unsuccessful.  The value either ends up as an empty string or null with whatever I try.  I have also tried setting viewFileName to @filePath without the single quotes as well as setting it to @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(filePath)).
This is what it looks like in the source code:

Calling OnGetViewFile inside a DataTables action.  This is called when a row is selected in the DataTable and a button to view the file is clicked.  (Actually viewing the file does not work.  Need to get the FilePath to be able to wire that up)
{
text: 'View File',
name: 'View',
className: 'dt-table-button',
action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
let selectedRow = dt.row('.selected').data();
$.ajax({
url: '?handler=ViewFile&fileName=' + selectedRow.FileName,
success: function (result) {
var filePath = '@filePath';
console.log(filePath);
},
error: function (xhr, status, error) {
alert('Error: The File was '  + error);
}
})
}
}

Hi @dev_in_training, how do you call ViewFile handler?

FYI Json.Serialize(string) === string

@Rena I'm not sure what you mean.  There is an ajax call to view the file in a dataTables action.

"I am setting the value of ViewData before returning to the view" ... "an ajax call" - there's your issue.  When the page is first rendered, the ViewData["FilePath"] will be null and this is what's being rendered into the script tag.  When you then make that call to OnGetViewFile, Razor can't update HTML already rendered (and displayed in the browser).  The js/ajax call to OnGetViewFile needs to handle the response and update the (now already defined) javascript variable.   ie in your current code, viewFileName='' runs before the ViewData is set.

@fdomm I'm not following.  I have a breakpoint set in the OnGetViewFile method where ViewData is getting set.  I also have a breakpoint set in the .cshtml where I am setting var filePath = ViewData["FilePath"] as string;  When the page first renders, filePath is null.  When I click on the button to trigger the call to OnGetViewFile, ViewData gets set, then the breakpoint is hit again for var filePath.  This time it has a value.  When I hover over '@fileName' in the js code it has a value but the js variable is getting set to an empty string.


page loads 2) js calls OnGetViewFile.   Your code in the question is sent to the browser in step 1 and rendered - it's not somehow "changed" in step 2.  Without seeing how you call OnGetViewFile (you say within datatables), can't really advise more other than trying for you to understand the concept of first-render vs ajax request.



Considering that your fileInfo.PhysicalPath; has backslashes, you would have to escape them fileInfo.PhysicalPath.Replace(@"\", @"\\"). You should now be able to access this in your Javascript code as @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@filePath)) or just plain '@filePath'.

If I can make a suggestion, on your button click, return a partial view with the ViewData and in your .chstml Page, set the <div> to the returned partial view and access the ViewData.


For example:
Index.cshtml:
<your data table div code>
<div class="file-content-container">
</div>

In your OnGetViewFile(), return the partial page with ViewData:
var resultViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<string>(ViewData, "Hello World");
resultViewData["FilePath"] = fileInfo.PhysicalPath.Replace(@"\", @"\\");            


return new PartialViewResult() { ViewData = resultViewData, ViewName = "_FileContentPartial" };

In your Javascript, try this:
$.ajax({

    url: '?handler=ViewFile&fileName=' + selectedRow.FileName',
    method: 'GET',    
    success: function (response) {
        $('.file-content-container').html(response);            
    },
    error: function () {
        console.error("An error occurred while retrieving.");
        $('.file-content-container').html('<p>An error occurred while retrieving.</p>');
    }
});

Your _FileContentPartial.cshtml would be something like:
@model string

@{
    var myFile = ViewData["FilePath"] as string;
    Console.WriteLine("FilePath: " + myFile);
}
<h3>FilePath01: @ViewData["FilePath"]</h3>

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(myFile: ' + '@myFile');
    let str1 = '@myFile';
    console.log(str1);
</script> 


I escaped the backslashes and have the same issue.  let viewFileName = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(filePath)); renders as null and let viewFileName = '@filePath' renders as an empty string.  When I debug @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(filePath)) and '@filePath'  have a value but the javascript variable never gets populated with that value.

Do you see any errors in your browser console?

there are no errors in the console.
